# What is the purpose of the black rectangular object behind Scott in "The Galileo Seven"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

When Scott electrifies the hull of the "Galileo," a piece of equipment is partially visible that looks like a circular chart recorder with pneumatic output.  What would a 23rd century Class F shuttle need with a piece of 1960s technology?

Comment: Is this what you are talking about? https://i2.wp.com/www.tor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/st-galileo16.jpg?resize=740%2C555&type=vertical

Comment: And you mean, a piece of 1960's technology in the 1960's that looks futuristic to the laypeople of the era?

Comment: @JohnP - Presumably this thing on the right of the frame; https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI3i1.png

Comment: @Valorum - Same item, better picture. Good find.

Comment: It's a Brown and Honeywell Circular Chart Recorder. They're used (typically) for [continuous temperature or pressure measurement](https://www.honeywellprocess.com/en-US/explore/products/instrumentation/recorders-and-data-acquisition/circular-chart-recorders/Pages/dr-4500-circular-chart-recorder.aspx); https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4535/38928845491_750009a7ef_b.jpg

Comment: Hey man don't discount the value of legacy equipment. Some high tech facilities today still use equipment and code bases built in an era so old most people never even heard of the languages. If it's solid, contained, and bullet proof, why upgrade? Maybe that Brown and Honeywell Circular Chart Recorder stood the very long test of time... lol, but still. Otherwise, John P nailed this one. You can't nitpick a zero budget show that happened to be amazing enough to be scrutinized over 40 years later

Comment: The German TV series [Raumpatrouille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raumpatrouille_%E2%80%93_Die_phantastischen_Abenteuer_des_Raumschiffes_Orion), also from the 60s, had to make do with a relatively low budget. So the set designers often re-tooled everyday items like electric irons, pencil sharpeners, clock pendulums or water faucets. The show is quite famous for that (among other things). Star Trek didn't start out as a money-laden franchise, either. So maybe the set designers there just used what they could get their hands on, too.

Comment: It was a Prop, it had no purpose. It was just a device that the average 1960s viewer would not have seen before, and would therefore look like some sort of Futuristic Engineering equipment. Remember, they needed some futuristic Salt Shakers for one of the early Shows, so went and got some. Then decided they did not look like Salt Shakers and just used a common one from the studio kitchen. But then took one of those fancy salt shakers and instead used it as the scanning device for DR McCoy's Medical Tri-corder.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the set designer had empty space to fill and used a true piece of technology.  This kind of ties in with what John P says.  It looks a lot like the ones I used to repair.

As Valorum stated, in the last half of the 20th century these were used for recording and indicating physical parameters.  I think the silver rectangle above the window said "Bailey".  Ink and paper recorders are becoming increasingly rare in our day and age with Distributed Control Systems (DCS) and Data Acquisition and Handling Systems (DAHS) being used. It seems systems like these are used in the various Star Trek franchises.  It seems the only place analog controls and ink on paper recorders are used is in the nuclear power industry in the U. S.